# ReactJS remove component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend

I'm trying to learn the basics of facebook's react.js library and I've been lately thinking about a few stuff I can do with it just to get used to the way it works . I'm trying to make a div that contains 2 buttons one is OPEN and the other is CLOSE, when you click the OPEN the react will render a div containing anything (Like a msg saying "You clicked"), this is  fine up to now but I cannot figure out how to make it disappear once clicked on the CLOSE button, does anyone know how to do that ? Thanks ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least four ways, that depends on the real problem you need to solve:

1) Add `#your-div-id.hidden { display:none }` styles and add/remove `hidden` class on click (maybe not React way)

2) Change view state (i.e. `opened` flag). That's a React way and maybe the simplest choice

```
onOpen() {
  this.setState({ opened: true });
}

onClose() {
  this.setState({ opened: false });
}

render() {
  var div = (this.state.opened) ? (<div>Your Div Content</div>) : undefined;
  return (
    //some your view content besides div
    {div}
  );
}
```

3) If you use Flux. Move state to `Store` and subscribe to changes. That maybe useful if you gonna  show your div at many parts of your app (i.e. implement error popups which may be shown at any part of an application).

So, first of all let's keep warnings at the store:

```
var CHANGE_EVENT = 'change';
const warnings = [];

var WarningsStore = assign({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
  getWarnings: () => return warnings,

  emitChange: () => this.emit(CHANGE_EVENT),

  addChangeListener: callback => this.on(CHANGE_EVENT, callback),

  removeChangeListener: callback => this.removeListener(CHANGE_EVENT, callback)
});

WarningsStore.dispatchToken = AppDispatcher.register(action => {

  switch(action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.ADD_WARNING:
      warnings.push(action.warning);
      WarningsStore.emitChange();
      break;
    case ActionTypes.DISMISS_WARNING:
      _.remove(warnings, {type: action.warningType}); //that's lodash or underscore method
      WarningsStore.emitChange();
      break;
  }
});
```

After we have a warnings store, you may subscribe to it from `YourView` and show popup on each `AppDispatcher.dispatch({type: ADD_WARNING, warningType: 'Error'});`

```
var YourView = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount: function() {
    WarningsStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    WarningsStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },

  _onChange() {
    this.setState({ warnings: WarningsStore.getWarnings() });
  },

  render() {
    //if we have warnigns - show popup
    const warnings = this.state.warnings,
          onCloseCallback = () => AppDispatcher.dispatch({type: DISSMISS_WARNING, warningType: warnings[0].warningType});
          popup = (warnings.length) ? <YourPopupComponent warning={warnings[0]} onClose={onCloseCallback}> : undefined;

    return (
      //here the main content of your view
      {popup}
    );
  }

})
```

4) If you simplified your example, but actually instead of div you need to show/hide another page - you should use react-router

Comment: Thank you, I liked the 2nd, just a question, when react renders uwillithe, wildisappear disappear ? Can't react add or remove class/use style sheets ?

Comment: @Noctisdark if you just need to add/remove classes from some components (DOM nodes) on user click then this may be what you looking for https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames. Just kep the `opened` state and calculate classes with `classnames`. The styles will apply on the fly as you change DOM node's classes

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do this:

```
var foo = React.CreateClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            showDiv: false, //Or true if you need it displayed immediately on open
        }
    },
    showIt: function() {
        this.setState({showDiv: true});
    },
    hideIt: function() {
        this.setState({showDiv: false});
    },

    render: function() {
        return (<div style={{display: this.state.showDiv ? 'block' : 'none'}}>Your content here</div>);
    }
});
```

What this will do is on state change, the style block of the div will be re-evaluated.  If the showDiv state variable is true, it'll display as a block element.  Otherwise it'll display none.  You could, in theory, do this with CSS as well.

[Here's a jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2vvu5xLr/1/) showing this being done with both CSS classes AND the style attribute on the div element.

Comment: Thanks !!, But is there any way to remove it completely ?

Comment: To remove it completely, you'd do something like what's in [here (another jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/85txLjom/1/).  Pretty much what happens in this instance is on the state change, it is going to re-render the component, which is going to run `this.renderDiv()` which either returns a `<div>` element or will return nothing (I think it returns `undefined`).  You could move the `this.renderDiv()` function contents into the `render()` method as well, but then you need to make a new variable object and set it to `undefined` to initialize, then run your `if` block.

Comment: Thank you much ^^, sorry because I cannot upvote (not enough reputation) but I really appreciate it ^^ I'm looking forward to really use this JS library, you are saving lives !

Comment: @Noctisdark no worries on upvote, but you could mark as answer ;)